# Problem after migrating Magento

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, seo, magento, url-rewriting

I am trying to create an exact mirror of a Magento production server on my local server for further development, but I have run into a few issues.

On the production server, our Magento is configured to run without displaying the `index.php`, but after attempting a migration to my local server, the `index.php` is required to access any links. Additionally, when I select a category to visit (for example), I am directed to `http://localhost/category.html` instead of `http://localhost/my-magento-store.com/index.php/category.html`

The other issue I've noticed is that I am unable to log in to the admin section. After entering the correct login credentials, I am redirected to the login screen again without any error messages.

I am running a MAMP stack on the local server, and here is what I have done:

1. Created a tar of the entire production server
2. Created a database backup in Magento `System > Tools > Backups`
3. Downloaded and extracted tar into local directory
4. Imported database dump into local MySQL using Alexey Ozerov's [big dump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.php) script. (The .sql file is 1.3m lines)
5. Changed values of `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in `core_config_data` table. (As I don't have a self-signed SSL cert, I put `http://localhost:8888/my-magento-store/` for both values)
6. Dumped contents of `var/cache` and `var/sesson`
7. Changed permissions to 755 for all files on local dev server
8. Navigated to `http://localhost:8888/my-magento-store/` but got the "Index of /" page instead.
9. Navigated to `http://localhost:8888/my-magento-store/index.php` and got an error.
10. Followed [these steps](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-error-%E2%80%93-notice-undefined-index-0-appcodecoremagecoremodelmysql4config-php-on-line-92/) to solve the error, reloaded the page, and the home page loaded correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL Rewriting depends on your .htaccess file, so there are a couple of things to check:

1. `web/seo/use_rewrites` in `core_config_data` should be `true`.
2. when you created your tarball, did it include `.` files in the root directory especially `.htaccess`?  If you used `tar -cvf archive.tar *` then it may have missed them.  (Nice "feature" of *nix).
3. Check that your MAMP `httpd.conf` has `AllowOverride All`, otherwise your local `.htaccess` will be ignored.
4. I'm not familiar with MAMP, but it's possible that it's having a problem reading/interpreting your .htaccess, though this is unlikely.  I'd focus on options 1 thru 3 first.

HTH,
JD

Comment: Thank you! It turned out that I was only missing the .htaccess files from my server which tar * wouldn't copy but tar ./ would.